# Count cumulative consecutive cells in Excel

Tags: excel, excel-formula

`I have the following table. I am looking for a formula to count consecutive 1's where each additional 1 in a string of 1's increases it's total count by 1`

```
Ex. two consecutive 1's yield 3 (1+2).
Ex. three consecutive 1's yield 6 (1+2+3).
Ex. Two consecutive 1's and one non-consecutive 1 yields 4 (1+2+1)'
```

| Col 1 | Col 2 | Col 3 | Col 4 | Col 5 | Score |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | 0 | 0 | 0 | 0 | 1 |
| 1 | 0 | 0 | 0 | 1 | 2 |
| 0 | 1 | 1 | 0 | 0 | 3 |
| 1 | 1 | 0 | 0 | 1 | 4 |
| 0 | 1 | 1 | 1 | 0 | 6 |

Answer (score 4):

Try something like:

[image]

Formula in `F2`:

```
=SUM(SCAN(0,A2:E2,LAMBDA(a,b,IF(b,a+b,0))))
```

Answer (score 2):

For Older versions that do not have SCAN and LAMBDA we need to use FREQUENCY and the formula `(n / 2)(first number + last number)`

```
=SUM((FREQUENCY(IF(A2:E2=1,COLUMN(A2:E2)),IF(A2:E2=0,COLUMN(A2:E2)))/2)*(1+FREQUENCY(IF(A2:E2=1,COLUMN(A2:E2)),IF(A2:E2=0,COLUMN(A2:E2)))))
```

In those older versions, this will require the use of Ctrl-Shift-Enter instead of Enter when exiting edit mode.  The use of SUMPRODUCT in place of SUM **MAY** negate that need, but I do not have an older version to test.

[image]